# apache camel mail: sending over smtps not working

Tags: java, email, smtp, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel (plain Java) and want to get smtps to work. Basically I just want to send a file via email and my route seems to start without problems, but no mail is sent and no error/exception is thrown.

```
INFO  Route: route7 started and consuming from: Endpoint[file://src/File.jpg?noop=true]
```

Interestingly the log "Sending Mail" is not shown.

My route class looks as follows:

```
public class SendToDepartment extends RouteBuilder {

public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("file:src/data/attachments/File.jpg?noop=true")
            .setHeader("subject", simple("New application"))
            .log("")
            .to("smtps://myname@gmx.at?password=secretpw&to=recipient@mail.com");
    }


}
```

Am I overlooking something here? I am using a free gmx.at email account - could this be the reason? In case that there was something wrong with the port or SSL I assume that Camel would throw it back at me. Does anyone know a free mail provider that works well with Camel? (doesn't need to have ssl because it's just for testing)

Comment: Please replace host name with IP address and see what is the result.

Comment: You can also add the debugMode=true option to your smtps uri to get more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I found out what the first mistake was: I can't use a filename in the path of the from-endpoint directly. I temporarily circumvented this by just specifying the directory:
    from("file:src/data/attachments?noop=true")
Now I get the following error:
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication credentials invalid
Now the route is running but I get an error:

Comment: ...
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication credentials invalid

I believe that this is because gmx uses multiple toplevel domains (gmx.net, gmx.at) and therefor I have to enter the full email address as username, but i'm not sure how to do this with Camel.

Comment: You can specify the username as `username=xxx` uri option - that is likely easier than in the authority part.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the input!

I succeeded by switching to Gmail and activating access for insecure apps in the preferences of the webUI. 
If anyone wants to do something similar, the last line looks like this now:

```
.to("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?username=fullemailaddress&password=secretpw&to=recipient@mail.com");
```